# How to model lookup tables JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I'm trying to build a Spring Boot data layer on top of another project's DB. I'm want to get to a point where I can consume their data via Restful endpoints rather than directly from the DB. Maximum abstraction is the goal. Here's my problem. Consider the following JPA entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON", schema = "public")
public class Person {
@Id private long id;
private String name;
private long favoriteFood;
private Address address;

//Getters, Setter etc.....
}
```

Notice that favoriteFood is a long, not a String. This is because the DB uses a lookup table. Let's say Joe's favorite food is pizza. The person table stores a 1 in the favorite_food column which is the fk to the "pizza" value stored in the food_ref table. This pattern is repeated hundreds or times in the DB. What is the best way to model this in JPA/Hibernate? Change the variable to String and have the getter and setter do the lookup? I've not found any examples which seems strange. This is a common DB structure. Any advice on best practices would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way in this scenario is to use **one to one** relationship in the JPA entity with the FoodRef class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON", schema = "public")
public class Person {
    @Id private long id;
    private String name;

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="food_ref_id")
    private FoodRef favoriteFood;

    private Address address;

    //Getters, Setter etc.....
}
```

Comment: I'd challenge the `fetch=FetchType,LAZY` attribute in the `@OneToOne` annotation, unless it's specifically needed in the project for some reason.

Comment: Person to FoodRef is clearly a ManyToOne relationship.